# git - после git push в origin репо файл завис в статусе Changes to be committed

Tags: git

Добрый вечер.  Гдя я не прав?

```
mkdir git_test_rebase
cd git_test_rebase/
cp /etc/passwd ./
git init
git add .
git commit -m "1"

cd ../
git clone  git_test_rebase git_test_rebase_clone
cd git_test_rebase_clone/
nano passwd

git add passwd
git commit -m "change passwd (from clone)"
git push origin master

cd git_test_rebase/

git log
commit 1d872be11d3efc3c8ee25b2bd7771a7660749207
change passwd (from clone)

commit 6bf1f58b2f74c415075cdfef971eb66d83e1a832
1

git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
modified:   passwd
```

Файл passwd не поменялся в папке git_test_rebase. Почему он завис в таком состоянии?
В .gitconfig только denyCurrentBranch = warn.
  Вроде сделал обычные операции, сделал коммит в изначальном репо, склонировал репо, в новом репо проделал изменения и сделал коммит, сделал пуш в origin. В origin repo коммит пришел, но файл по git status завис в таком состоянии.

Comment: push по умолчанию не мерджит изменения

Comment: По хорошему, нужно пушить в bare репу, а там на post-receive обновлять файлы где-нибудь рядом..

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добиться ожидаемого Вами поведения можно изменить конфигурацию remote:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: @unix196 получилось?

Comment: у меня старая версия git на дебиане jessie, которая не поддерживает указанную опцию (не стал заморачиваться на установку более новой версии из backports). Поэтому просто переделал на bare репозиторий.